# Can I travel to Paris with Eurostar using my British provisional driving license?

Tags: international-travel, paperwork, eurostar

Specifically from London St Pancras International.

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No.

The UK is not in the [Schengen area](http://europa.eu/youreurope/citizens/travel/entry-exit/eu-citizen/index_en.htm) (area without border checks) so you need a passport:

> Can I use my driving licence as an ID document at the border?
>
> NO - A driving licence isn't a travel document. You'll need a valid national identity card or passport.

[FAQs - Travel documents for EU nationals](http://europa.eu/youreurope/citizens/travel/entry-exit/eu-citizen/faq/index_en.htm)

(NB: a UK driving licence is not the same thing as a 'national identity card'. It doesn't prove British citizenship because someone who isn't a British citizen can still qualify for a British driving licence).

If the image means that you intend to try to use fake ID, then this document which shows [the security features built-in to a genuine driving licence (p.19/20)](https://www.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/98108/false-id-guidance.pdf) might be of interest. Trying to use a fake ID to cross a national border would (obviously) be a fairly serious crime. The foreword adds:

> The fake ID cards which can be ordered on the internet often do not replicate existing documents. Examples include the UK national identification card and a provisional motorcycle licence. It is an offence under section 1 of the Forgery and Counterfeiting Act 1981 to make a false instrument with the intention to use it to induce a person to accept it as genuine, and by reason of so accepting it to do or not to do some act which is to their own or any other person’s prejudice. However, fake ID cards are commonly sold as novelty items and the companies that produce them are often foreign-based. Therefore, it is difficult for the UK to prevent or restrict the production of these items.

Comment: What Is “Freedom of Movement” in the European Union then? Also driving license is an ID in The UK

Comment: @Ulkoma a DL may be accepted in the UK as ID, but it is not a travel document, so it does not count as a "national ID" for the purpose of traveling in the EU.  Notably, it does not report the bearer's nationality.  Similarly, a Dutch DL can be used for ID for certain purposes in the Netherlands, but not for others, and not as a travel document for crossing borders.  Crossing an external border of the EU requires a travel document.  Because the UK decided to opt out of the common border scheme, crossing from the UK to a Schengen state counts as crossing an external border.

Comment: Freedom of movement is described here: http://ec.europa.eu/social/main.jsp?catId=457 It means if you're a UK citizen you can move freely through the EU to look for a job (in the same way that citizens of other EU countries can in the UK), but it doesn't mean that you or they don't need a passport.

Comment: @phoog your comment can be an answer.

Comment: @AE my ID isn't fake and you cant tell a fake ID from an image, you don't expect me to post an unmodified version of my driving license of SE, do you?

Comment: @Ulkoma, no, absolutely, you definitely shouldn't do that! No need to post one at all. I'll leave it up to you to work out how I can know for sure that the pictured provisional driving licence is a fake...

Comment: @Ulkoma Aside from the fact that it's advertising "fakeidking" and the format doesn't match that of DLs from 2013?

Comment: @Ulkoma, the EU freedom of movement applies to EU citizens (and a few others). So in order to cross the border without visa, you have to show that you're an UK citizen. A date and place of birth entry shows citizenship.

Comment: @o.m. Did you mean "does not show citizenship"?

Comment: @Relaxed, yeah, my typo.